# Freeradius problem with redundant-load-balance LDAP-Group

Tags: ldap, load-balancing, freeradius, redundancy

I need to assign the user the vlan corresponding to the group in active directory after the user has authenticated via EAP-TLS.
I created the script that handles the vlan assignment in /policy.d/vlan_assignment:

```
vlan_assignment {
    if (LDAP-Group == "CN=radiusClient,CN=Users,DC=myGroup,DC=dom") {
        update reply {
    [...]
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly with only one ldap server enabled in mods-enabled.
I would like to use the redundant-load-balance function offered by freeradius.

In radius.conf, modules section, I create the configuration of the two ldap servers:

```
modules {
    ldap server1 {
            server = 'SRVAD01'
            port = 389
           [...]
    }
    ldap server2 {
            server = 'SRVAD02'
            port = 389
           [...]
    }
}
```

and in the instantiate section

```
instantiate {
    redundant-load-balance rlb_ldap {
        server1
        server2
    }   
}
```

The connection to the ldap servers occurs only in the post_auth section of my site outer-tunnel.

```
server outer-tunnel {
    listen {
    [...]
    }
    authorize {
        filter_username
        preprocess
        auth_log
        suffix
        eap {
            ok = return
            updated = return
        }
        sql
        expiration
        logintime
        pap
    }
    authenticate {
        Auth-Type PAP {
            pap
        }
        pam
        eap
    }
    preacct {
        preprocess
        acct_unique
        suffix
    }
    accounting {
        detail
        unix
        sql
        exec
        attr_filter.accounting_response
    }
    session {
        sql
    }
    post-auth {
        update {
            &reply: += &session-state:
        }   
       #*****edit ****         
        rlb_ldap.authorize
        if (ok || updated) {
            update session-state {
                &LDAP-Group += &LDAP-Group[*]
            }
        }
        #********************
        vlan_assignment
        exec
        [...]
    }
        [...]
}
```

But I have the following error in policy.d/vlans_assignent when starting freeradius -X :

> Unknown attribute 'LDAP-Group'

I read and searched for solutions but failed. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've created instances of the LDAP module, so the LDAP-Group attribute's name has changed.  There are a few ways to solve this, but the easiest is to instruct the LDAP module to use the same attribute for all its instances, and then have it retrieve the complete membership listing.

For each LDAP module, uncomment and set [cache_attribute](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.0.x/raddb/mods-available/ldap#L333) to be the same.  This can just be set to 'LDAP-Group' if you want.

Then, again, for each LDAP module, uncomment and set [cacheable_dn](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.0.x/raddb/mods-available/ldap#L327) to 'yes'.

You may need to call rlb_ldap to pre-populate the group information, before you attempt any group checks, else the group check will just hit one LDAP or or the other, and you won't get redundancy.

If you're using EAP, and pulling out LDAP information in the innter-tunnel you'll need to store the group membership information in the session state list and restore it before checking membership information again.

To store LDAP group information:

```
ldap
if (ok || updated) {
    update session-state {
        &LDAP-Group += &LDAP-Group[*]
    }
}
```

To restore it:

```
update request {
    update request {
        &LDAP-Group += &session-state:LDAP-Group[*]
    }
}
```

If you're pulling group information in the inner server, you'll need to change `update session-state` to `update outer.session-state`.

Another potential issue you may have, is that you're listing rlb_ldap in post-auth, but aren't overriding the method.  This means when rlb_ldap is called it will perform its normal post-auth duties, which are modifying a user's object in the LDAP directory to record the last time then logged in.

To fix this, change your rlb_ldap call to `rlb_ldap.authorize`, this will result in the group membership information being retrieved instead.

Comment: Hi Arran, I'm sorry but I didn't understand where to enter the code to store the LDAP group information.
In outer-tunnel? and in which section?
The virtual inner-tunnel server, I hope I'm not wrong, it's not interesting for my configuration because I don't use EAP-TTLS or PEAP ...

Comment: ah never mind then.  Updated the answer again.  You need to use ``rlb_ldap.authorize`` when you're calling it in the post-auth section.

Comment: Hi @Arran Cudbard-Bell, I added in the post-auth outer-tunnel section:
rlb_ldap.authorize
  
if (ok || updated) {  
    update session-state {  
        & LDAP-Group + = & LDAP-Group [*]  
    }  
}  
  
vlan_assignment  
  
Starting freeradius -X and after eap authentication, I still can't store LDAP group information. This is the log of the post-auth section:
https://pastebin.com/kWQ5D8gL

Comment: Hm, weird, doesn't seem to be picking up the right paircmp function. `&control:LDAP-Group[*] == '<group name>'` should work.